# Backbone method to check before fetch call

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

Is there any method or a filter which executes before making call to fetch.

I got **ajaxPrefilter** but it filters just the ajax request and not backbone.

How do i achieve that in backbone?

Comment: You want to do this globally for every backbone object?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do: modify your api call? Check your model attributes? Initiate some other logic?

I think in a lot of cases, your needs might be met by the Backbone Model `validate` method (https://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate). If you write such a method into your model, it will run before every save (and thus before every fetch). This may not work for modifying the api call, but you could use it to - you know - *validate* your model before save, or to call some other method / initialize some other logical process.